# Cisco switches LACP, lost connections

Tags: cisco, lacp

I just put up a LACP between two Cisco SG-200 switches.

Unfortunately some PCs connected to these switches got problems like lost Postgres connections etc.

My configuration is simple:

```
----------------             ----------------
|   switch_1   | =========== |   switch_2   |
|              | =========== |              |
----------------             ----------------

LAG ports: GE45, GE46, GE47, GE48 on both switches
Load Balance Algorithm: IP/MAC Address
```

Postgresql show logs:

```
could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

My LACP config: imgur.com/a/4yfAzOV

[image]

[image]

[image]

What could be the reason?

Comment: Does it work if you disconnect all but one link?

Comment: You mean disconnect LAG patch cords except one?

Comment: Exactly, that should basically force the LAG to use only one port, effectively removing the LAG without any configuration changes, and shows you if the issue is the balancing algorithm used or something else.

Comment: Disconnected all LAG cables, except 1. In general, is the use of port aggregation for a switch connection correct?

Comment: Ok, did it affect how things work? Port aggregation is quite common in enterprise networks between for example two large switches where you need all the link capacity. If you just want redundancy, Spanning Tree is usually used.

Comment: The logs are empty and everything looks stable. Any idea why LACP not working correctly?

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind when using LAGs is how the traffic is balanced, if you have a lot of clients talking to a single server, you want to balance according to the MAC address of the sender, because if you balance according to the destination, all traffic will go through one of the links and the other ones won't get used.

Comment: So i try to change balance algorithm from IP/MAC Address to MAC Address but probably I tried to change it before - without result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup Switch 1 in LACP Passive and Swtich 2 in LACP Active (or vice-versa)?
If you have both switchs in ACTIVE mode they will both try to negotiate the LACP and that can cause you some problems. (not sure if these settings are configurable on a SG200).
If possible share your LAG/LACP configurations with us.

Comment: My configs (cant post images): https://imgur.com/a/4yfAzOV - I haven't found anywhere active / passive mode (maybe it's called master / slave ? )

Comment: Added the images in line for you. :)